# Скрипт на Python переписать

Tags: python, bash

Добрый день у меня есть скрипт который выполняет post запрос написанный на python, помогите мне переписать его на BASH

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import requests
import json
import sys

to = sys.argv[1]
subject = sys.argv[2]
url="https://infobip.com/"
headers = {
            "Authorization":"Basic ",
            "Content-Type":"application/json",
            "Accept":"application/json"
          }

payload = {
            "from":"SK",
             "to":to,
            "text":subject
          }

p = json.dumps(payload)    
r = requests.post(url=url,data=p,headers=headers)
```

Comment: Это не вопрос. Дайте свой вариант кода и тога мы поможем

Comment: К сожаления я не знаю как его написать на bash, если б знал то не спрашивал бы, и гугл не помогает.

Comment: А мне было бы интересно узнать - а зачем это нужно или что это даст?

Comment: Пытаюсь прикрутить к системе мониторинга zabbix  отправку смс, но он почему то не хочет передавать аргументы в скрипт (хотя пишет что успешно отправил), а если через консоль выполнить то все ок. то есть сам скрипт рабочий. Погуглил, все пишут на bashe, вот теперь думаю что нужно как то его переписать. в программирование совсем не селен. просто инсрукций понятных на питоне много, а на bashe чего то нет

Answer (score 1):

Может нет прав на исполнение?

```
to = sys.argv[1]
subject = sys.argv[2]
```

После этого добавьте:

```
print(to, subject)
```

Из под пользователя от которого работает забикс попробуйте выполнить

```
/path_to_script/scpipt.py hello world
```

Печатает ('hello', 'world')?

Comment: пишет This account is currentle not available... видимо дело не в pythone

Comment: Вот кста на хабре, может будет интересно, мне кажется Вам стоит немного переформулировать вопрос на тему забикса и доп скриптов - https://m.habrahabr.ru/post/325876/